# expressing the idea that you are a child of a marriage, in which parents belong to different races

Tags: phrase-request

What's the natural way in English to express the idea that you are a child of a marriage, in which parents belong to different races?

1. "I am a cross-cultural marriage kid."?
2. "I am a cross cultural family kid."?
3. "I am a biracial kid."?
4. "I am a child from a biracial marriage."?

Comment: "Culture" is not the same as "race". If my father is Caucasian English and my mother Caucasian German I may still be a "cross cultural" kid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixed-race is the answer. In America, the term 'mixed' is often used. People say biracial, but that is used in more formal contexts, like doctors visits. Most people who are bi-racial would say "I'm mixed."

Comment: Thank you. Can you, please, also direct me in how to use it with the word 'family'? Can I, for example, say "I am a mixed family kid" or would it be better to say something like "I am from a mixed family"?

Comment: I'm *not* from a family with racially distinct parents, but I'd have thought most people who *are* wouldn't want to talk about their domestic circumstances in that way. People who have opposite-sex siblings don't say *I come from a **mixed sex** family* (Yeah, yeah - I know we all come from "mixed sex" *parents!* :)

Comment: @brilliant "I'm from a family of different races". You wouldn't really use mixed here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _ I am afraid I didn't quite get your point here.

Comment: @Elainor - I see. Thank you!

Comment: @brilliant: My point is that "the natural way in English to express that" your two parents belong to different *races* would probably be very different from the way *other people* might describe your circumstances. Things have moved on today, but 50 years ago the way most cohabiting *homosexuals* described their domestic circumstances wasn't normally the same as the way other people would describe it. And I *don't* mean to imply other people's descriptions might be homophobic - it would just be *different*.